# How to access Dataset from.cs to .aspx using eval()

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am coding Gridview programmatically.
I have dataset in code behind part(.cs),when i am trying to access the dataset in .aspx page using Eval() "Error Creating Control" error is coming.

Is it the Right way using Eval()?

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblGridTier" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval(dt.Tables[0].Columns["Tier"])%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I'd rather advice you to use databind in the .cs file and access the databound events to fill in the data, or make a list of DTOs and bind the grid to the properties of that.
It provides a better programming model and some performance over eval.

Comment: How are you binding your gridview with data?

Comment: could you please add code here so i can have a look at it.

Comment: I may have may columns in dataset but i need only selected columns in the gridview. @AllanS.Hansen as U said,i binded the dataset in .cs but i am trying to display only certain columns fron the dataset.

Comment: a) don't pull more data from the database than needed. b) when getting the dataset, map it to a list of DTOs, then you can use the property name to map the columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing something like this in the code behind to bind the GridView (and you actually should do something like this):

```
DateSet ds = ...
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

then the correct way to use eval is to give it just the name of the column you want to show.

```
Text='<%#Eval("Tier")%>'
```

Comment: If Dataset  contains more than one table with same column name,how eval going to handle tht ?

Comment: @kranthiv, frankly speaking I am not sure. You can try and see what happens anyway. Although you might want to simply `GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];` and avoid this (if you want to).

Answer (score 0):

ok please note html is rendered first then your code behind file is called. Now here dataset is null (not yet created) when HTML is being rendered dataset is null so control will not be created and an exception will be thrown. You can use this work around on Page_Load you can set text property of label or check here if dataset is null then don't assign value using Eval. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Eval function evaluates fields directly from the selected table of datasource which your grid is bound with. A couple of examples as follows:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblSomeField" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("field1")%>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:Image ID="lblImageLink" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("imagefield", "http://somelink.com/images/{0}")%>' />
        <asp:HyperLink ID="lblMember" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "/member.aspx?id=" + Eval("id") %>' Text='<%# Eval("membername") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```